# Proper way to accept multiple clients?

Tags: c, multithreading, server, client

I am working on a project which involves a multi-threaded server which should theoretically be able to accept any number of clients at the same time. Upon each client-connection to the server, a new thread needs to be spawned to serve the needs of the client. I am confused whether the listen() function plays any part of this. Does this need to be in an infinite loop? Should I only be listening for one client connection at a time?

When I call the listen function, I pass the socket file descriptor and the number of connections, which in my case, I pass 5. I do not run this in a loop or anything, I just call it once. However, I do not think this is the proper way to do it considering the implementation I need

```
// now the server can listen
int listennum = listen(socketfd, 5); 
if (listennum != 0) {
   printf("Listen has failed..\n"); 
   exit(0); 
} 
else {
   printf("Server is listening..\n"); 
}
```

Comment: The `listen()` function should be in an infinite loop. This function, as its name says, keeps listening for client connections/requisitions. When a client connection/requisition arrives, `listen()` creates another job/process that deals with the incoming connection/requisition and goes back to listening again.

Comment: should I be calling it as listen(socketfd, 1) in an infinite loop? or am i able to listen for multiple connections at once?

Comment: No, @IagoCarvalho, making `listen` loop infinitely is in no way required.  It is only the `accept()` that must loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused whether the `listen()` function plays any part of this.
>   Does this need to be in an infinite loop?

No.  `listen()` sets a property of a socket, marking it as a passive socket by which the program can accept connections.  It is not necessary to do that more than once.  Do not forget to `bind()` the socket first (which you should also do only once).

> Should I only be listening
>   for one client connection at a time?

That's not really a concept that the socket interface affords, though there is the related concept of how many connections awaiting acceptance can be queued for the socket at once.  That's controlled by the second parameter to `listen()`.

> When I call the listen function, I pass the socket file descriptor and
>   the number of connections, which in my case, I pass 5. I do not run
>   this in a loop or anything, I just call it once.

That's exactly what you should do, but it's not the *only* thing you should do.

> However, I do not
>   think this is the proper way to do it considering the implementation I
>   need

You are perhaps missing that after calling `listen()`, you must use the `accept()` function to actually accept connections.  *That* is what you want to run in a loop.  You can accept any number of connections from the same listening socket.

Comment: so both the listen() and accept() should be in loops or am I able to call listen() once and then loop for accept()?

Comment: `listen` once.  `accept` as many times as needed.  I'm not sure how this answer as already written affords a different interpretation.